# Access item inside Unity sharedassets.assets file programmatically in C# Mono

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, cities-skylines-api

I'm working on a Cities: Skylines mod and I want to access the sharedassets.assets file(s) the game has in the Data folder programmatically to get a mesh/prefab.

I've found a tool called Unity Assets Bundle Extractor (UABE) and it is able to open up these files and extract the mesh.

Is there a way to extract a mesh from the sharedassets programmatically with C# code like UABE does?

I've looked in the Unity documentation but so far only have seen this page (not sure if relevant): https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetBundle.LoadFromFile.html

I tried adapting the code from there but I haven't had any success so far, only have had not found error messages

```
var myLoadedAssetBundle = AssetBundle.LoadFromFile(Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, "sharedassets11"));
```

Is there a way to achieve this? Thanks

Comment: Have you found a solution since ? I have the exact same problem...

Answer (score 1):

Look at the API for [`AssetBundle.LoadFromFile`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetBundle.LoadFromFile.html?_ga=1.259297550.563709772.1479226228).

There is a second method [`AssetBundle.LoadAsset`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetBundle.LoadAsset.html) (or alternatively also maybe [`AssetBundle.LoadAllAssets`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetBundle.LoadAllAssets.html)) you will need:

> ```
> var myLoadedAssetBundle = AssetBundle.LoadFromFile(Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, "sharedassets11"));
> if (myLoadedAssetBundle == null)
> {
>     Debug.Log("Failed to load AssetBundle!");
>     return;
> }
>
> var prefab = myLoadedAssetBundle.LoadAsset<GameObject>("NameOfTheAccordingObject");
> Instantiate(prefab);
>
> myLoadedAssetBundle.Unload(false);
> ```

Comment: The game doesn't seem to store anything under Application.streamingAssetsPath. The file I'm looking for is stored in Application.dataPath folder. Currently the variations of code I've tried based on this fail on the first line

Comment: It was just the example from the API. Of course use your correct file path and name! ;)

Comment: no luck with pasted code, it finds the file though always returns with 'Failed to load AssetBundle'. Also tried adding .assets extension to the file path

Comment: Error Message (with .assets added to filename): Unable to open archive file: C:/Program Files (x86)/Steam/steamapps/common/Cities_Skylines/Cities_Data/sharedassets11.asset
(Filename:  Line: 483)
Failed to load AssetBundle!